# How can I reinstall a system PL/SQL package in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, package, system

I have noticed that if someone overwrites or deletes a system package you cannot recover the initial code.  In my case, I have lost DBMS_OUTPUT package. Does anyone knows how to reinstall it ?

Comment: I think backup the schema and re create the DB is the best options, but one thing you can try is to look for the file dbmsotpt.sql , and see if you can execute that (dont know if it will work)

Comment: You *can* sometimes view the previous version of the code with a flashback query like this: `select * from dba_source as of timestamp systimestamp - interval '10' minute where name = 'DBMS_OUTPUT';` Although you'll need to be logged in as SYS to run that command against system objects. And system objects are often weird and may not be easy to reinstall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package is created with the scripts dbmsotpt.sql (package spec) and then prvtotpt.plb (package body), though I have never executed these scripts directly. The scripts can be found under /rdbms/admin.

Comment: Thanks, the script prvtotpt.plb solved my problem! I only had to execute it as SYS user.